# Passing string from one Python class to a QTextEdit field of another class (QGIS plugin)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, pyqt

I've an input mask that feeds a spatialite database.

I have one Python file which does all the work and two Qt Ui-Files (Ui_InputMask, Ui_Items).

In the main form (`class mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_InputMask)`) I can open a new form (`class items_mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_Items)`) which shows me some check boxes. After I check some I want to pass the information to a QTextEdit of the main form class.

Here is the shortened code:

```
        ....

class items_mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_Items):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pass_items.clicked.connect(self.getItems)
        self.abort_items.clicked.connect(self.closeItems)

    def getItems(self):
        getItemList = [['val1','description1'],['val2','description2']]
        ItemList = []
        for l in getItemList:
            checkboxstring = str(l[0])
            checkboxname = checkboxstring.strip()
            checkbox = getattr(self, checkboxname)
            if checkbox.isChecked():
                ItemList.append(l[1])
        ItemListText = '%s' % ', '.join(map(str, ItemList))
        QMessageBox.critical(iface.mainWindow(),'Input...', ItemListText)

    def closeItems(self):
        self.close()

class mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_InputMask):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        global now
        now = datetime.datetime.now()

        global username
        username = getpass.getuser()

        ...

       self.choose_items.clicked.connect(self.itemCallMask)

        ...

    def itemCallMask(self):
        items_mask = items_mask_n_functions(self)
        items_mask.show()

        ...
```

I googled: "python how to pass variables between classes", but I don't know how to implement this for my plugin structure.

`Ui_InputMask` contains the QTextEdit I want to fill with `ItemListText` of the class `items_mask_n_functions`.

Within one class I set Text to a QTextEdit like this: `self.qtextedit_tofill.setText('some text')`.

Comment: in your class items_mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_Items),put self.parent=parent,in your call put  items_mask = items_mask_n_functions(self,parent=self) and when you want pass any value only write self.parent.qtextedit_tofill.setText('some text')

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It works now. I don't have to put `items_mask = items_mask_n_functions(self,parent=self)`. When I do this the InputMask doesn't open anymore. Setting `self.parent=parent` was enough in my case.

Comment: Please write an answer with the help of your comment and please describe it for other persons who are reading this. It would be great if you explain how the variables were passed between classes in my plugin and what's it all about `self.parent=parent`.

Comment: add a little explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need pass a object (**QDialog**) in this case from Python class to other Python class, In your example only is neccesary put ,`self.parent=parent` in your `items_mask_n_functions` class,in this way, you can call all methods of the parent from , for example `self.parent.qtextedit_tofill.setText('some text')` where `qtextedit_tofill` is a **QTextEdit** object in the parent class.

```
        ....

class items_mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_Items):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.parent=parent

        self.pass_items.clicked.connect(self.getItems)
        self.abort_items.clicked.connect(self.closeItems)

    def getItems(self):
        getItemList = [['val1','description1'],['val2','description2']]
        ItemList = []
        for l in getItemList:
            checkboxstring = str(l[0])
            checkboxname = checkboxstring.strip()
            checkbox = getattr(self, checkboxname)
            if checkbox.isChecked():
                ItemList.append(l[1])
        ItemListText = '%s' % ', '.join(map(str, ItemList))
        QMessageBox.critical(iface.mainWindow(),'Input...', ItemListText)

        #For example or self.parent.qtextedit_tofill.setText('some text')
        self.parent.qtextedit_tofill.setText(ItemListText)

    def closeItems(self):
        self.close()

class mask_n_functions(QDialog, Ui_InputMask):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        QDialog.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        global now
        now = datetime.datetime.now()

        global username
        username = getpass.getuser()

        ...

       self.choose_items.clicked.connect(self.itemCallMask)

        ...

    def itemCallMask(self):
        items_mask = items_mask_n_functions(self)
        items_mask.show()

        ...
```